# May you please provide a way to reward very helpful comments?

Tags: discussion

I have a happy Friday story today. It involves a large SQL query and some hair-pulling.

I was stuck on a large SQL query, and at my wit's end. So, in a panicky rush, I decided to lean on StackOverflow.

I drew up my question, trying to make it look meaty enough(and in doing so, making it look a little very unfriendly and monstrous).

Then I [posted the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516886/where-is-the-bug-in-my-sql-join-logic). And nobody answered.

So I went into the most logical place for help, the C++ chat lounge.

Soon my post had **-7** on it, numerous close votes.. and I considered changing my name and moving far away.

But... amidst the fire and mayhem, a few experts pitched in comments. And one was really helpful to me: it goes -

> Using securityRow in the WHERE clause when you have it in the left
>   join will make it behave like an INNER JOIN. I'd break this down and
>   add a single table at a time to see where the problem is

I happen [to know that this user is pretty modest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet), so I won't divulge the name(unless said user wants to be put in limelight )

This one little comment fixed my problem. To me, it was a godsend.

Thank You StackOverflow!!

Comment: Am I off-topic ? I know I'm offtopic. I'll sip more coffee. PEACE

Comment: Meta you're a tough sell

Comment: And then I found 5 dollars.

Comment: @ryanyuyu - And a $50 starbucks card : \

Comment: @ping the comment author and ask to submit it as a proper answer. Then you can show your appreciation by marking it as accepted.

Comment: If you want, I can post it as an answer so you can mark it "Accepted". (... just kidding: I see Makoto already did so).

Comment: @Jongware - There is a small "catch" I didn't tell you, which is thta my question was closed quickly... and so even if I asked user to make answer it is impossible. Not that that changes the general idea of it, IK

Comment: FYI *"in a panicky rush, I decided to lean on StackOverflow"* is exactly how **not** to use SO.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  - Agreed, you are right. My apologies sir

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got a couple of options:

- Vote on their comment
- Ask them to create an answer (which you'd subsequently upvote and/or accept)

Comments aren't the point of this site, so anything outside of that is doing entirely too much.

Comment: Sure.  Next time, enjoy caffeine responsibly.

Comment: Absolutely, unless the question is already on hold and does not accept new answers.

Comment: @PM77-1:  Ooh, you got me there.  Although I'd describe that as more of an uncommon case than the norm.

Comment: @PM77-1 which in this case, it is closed.

Comment: It's a fair point though. If the question was closed for being unclear or too broad, it may be possible to edit it into shape and get placed in the Reopen Queue.

Comment: @bluefeet  -  HEY!!

Comment: @Jongware - Ok, I will try to clean it up then

Comment: @bluefeet - Thank You my friend :  )